# How to design a simple game map in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making a very very simple game in Android, and I'm not using OpenGL or any other libraries, just Java!

Now I'm stuck in designing my map...

I want to design something like this:

[image: Working with Paint is hard! :|]

(Those lines should consider as walls and players can't get out of them)

How to design something like this using XML only? Or I should start using Unity3D?

Comment: Jumping from xml to Unity3d is a hell-of-a-leap, especially if it's "very very simple." Why not just make a photoshop image and scale it for various screen sizes?

Comment: Would this tutorial be if any help to you.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/01/creat-background-of-popup-window-with.html?m=1

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I can't use image, because I need to have the borders positions, so I can control my players for not getting out of it!

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE No, it's using an XML shape, as I said in previous comment, I need to have the borders positions...

Comment: I think you could still do it with multiple images, but maybe that's more than what you're expecting. You would need a total of three (it would actually just be one scaled and rotated) : a short for the corner, a medium for the top/bottom, and a large for the sides. If the image was the same size as the "wall" you could certainly use the image for collisions. Should be able to do the same thing with basic drawn shapes.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Hmmm, interesting... But there's still a problem here: If I rotate an image and use getX(), it'll show me the X of un-rotated image, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't done with xml, but you neither need any libraries.

```
public class Background extends View {

    private static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 2; //in px

    private int[] points; //2n = x, 2n+1 = y

    public Background(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for(Drawable drawable : drawBackground()){
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    private Drawable[] drawBackground() {
        Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[2];

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int corner = width / 4;

        //draw border
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0, corner);
        path.lineTo(corner, 0);
        path.lineTo(width, 0);
        path.lineTo(width, height - corner);
        path.lineTo(width - corner, height);
        path.lineTo(0, height);
        path.close();

        drawables[0] = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, width, height));
        drawables[0].setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

        //draw inside the border
        points = {
            BORDER_WIDTH, corner,
            corner, BORDER_WIDTH,
            width - BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH,
            width - BORDER_WIDTH, height - corner,
            width - corner, height - BORDER_WIDTH,
            BORDER_WIDTH, height - BORDER_WIDTH
        }
        path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(points[0], points[1]);
        for (int i = 2, i < points.length, i++) {
            path.lineTo(points[i], points[++i]);
        }
        path.close();

        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, width, height));
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.rgb(238, 238, 238));
        shapeDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        drawables[1] = shapeDrawable;

        return drawables;
    }

    public Point[] getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: Result of the class]

Comment: Nice! Can I access the positions of these lines? Something like Line.getX() or getY() or getHeight()?
(Would you please give me a good source about how to work with Path?

Comment: @MR.Garcia Do you want to edit the positions or acces them after the view is drawn?

Comment: As I said in the question "(Those lines should consider as walls and players can't get out of them)", so I should have their positions, right?

Comment: In that case, no you can't acces the positions after putting them in the `Path`. You can put the points in a global array first, and then iterate over them. then you can acces the positions by calling `getPoints()`. I edited the code.